# Extracting Numeric value from SQLite

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

My SQLite field is a numeric type (int).
When i try to extract it into my application like this:

```
int id_quiz= (NSInteger) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
```

i got a huge value like `129600224` which is not the correct one (and it changes every time i run the app).

However, in the same table, i got string value from other fields just fine:

```
NSString *question = [[NSString alloc] 
                                          initWithUTF8String:
                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                             statement, 1)];
```

The question is, how can i get a numeric value from SQLite? 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int id_quiz =sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```

[for more information SQLite](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the column as an `int`, not as "text":

```
int id_quiz = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
```